# Order barplot according to two non-plotted columns

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a dataset to plot with a structure like this:

```
set.seed(17)

t <- tibble(country = c(rep("AUS", 5), rep("DNK", 5), rep("FIN", 5)),
       year = rep(seq(from = 1995, to = 1999, length.out = 5), 3),
       apples = abs(rnorm(15, 5, 2)),
       pears = abs(rnorm(15, 4,1)),
       bananas = abs(rnorm(15, 6, 2))) %>%
  pivot_longer(., cols = c(apples, bananas, pears), names_to = "variable", values_to = "value") %>%
  mutate(country = fct_relevel(country, c("DNK", "FIN", "AUS")),
         cyear = paste0(country, year))
```

Note the order of `country` (`DNK`, `FIN`, `AUS`), which I would like to preserve in the plot.

I now plot the country-year combinations with the following code.

```
t %>%
  ggplot(., aes(fill=variable, y=value, x = cyear)) + 
  scale_fill_brewer(name = "Fruits", labels = names)+
  geom_bar(position = "fill", stat="identity") +
  labs(x = "Country code", y = "Variable", title = "Title") + 
  theme_bw() +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90))
```

[image: plot sample]

However, I would like

1. the cases to be sorted according to the order of country and then numerically within years (i.e. DNK1995, DNK1996, DNK1999, FIN1995, ..., FIN1999, AUS1995, AUS1999) and
2. the x-axis to display the entries of `country` in horizontal writing and the year in vertical writing, since it otherwise is too crowded (i.e. DNK in horizontal orientation centred under the respective entries 1995, 1996, ..., in vertical orientation etc.).

Can someone point out how to best achieve this?

EDIT: The actual data frame has 22 countries and different years, so I couldn't get it to work with `facet_wrap()` and `facet_grid()` with shared x-axes because there were too many entries there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edited to add a non-facet solution:**

Here's another potential solution. The tricky part is setting the data up to mimic a stacked bar when in reality it's overlaid:

```r
library(tidyverse)

set.seed(17)

t1 <- tibble(
  country = c(rep("AUS", 5), rep("DNK", 5), rep("FIN", 5)),
  year = rep(seq(from = 1995, to = 1999, length.out = 5), 3),
  apples = abs(rnorm(15, 5, 2)),
  pears = abs(rnorm(15, 4, 1)),
  bananas = abs(rnorm(15, 6, 2))
) %>%
  mutate(country = fct_relevel(country, c("DNK", "FIN", "AUS"))) %>%
  rowwise() %>%
  mutate(
    across(apples:bananas, ~ .x / sum(c_across(apples:bananas))),
    apples = sum(c_across(apples:bananas)),
    bananas = sum(c_across(pears:bananas))
  ) %>%
  pivot_longer(
    cols = c(apples, bananas, pears),
    names_to = "variable",
    values_to = "value"
  )

t1 %>%
  ggplot(aes(fill = variable, y = value, x = country, label = year, group = year)) +
  scale_fill_brewer(name = "Fruits") +
  geom_bar(position = "dodge", stat = "identity", color = "white") +
  geom_text(position = position_dodge(width = .9), aes(x = country, y = -.06), size = 3, angle = 90) +
  labs(x = "Country", y = "Variable", title = "Title") +
  theme_bw()
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2021-04-30 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v1.0.0)</sup>

**Original solution:**

One possible solution is yielded with use of `facet_grid()`:

```r
library(tidyverse)

t <- tibble(
  country = c(rep("AUS", 5), rep("DNK", 5), rep("FIN", 5)),
  year = rep(seq(from = 1995, to = 1999, length.out = 5), 3),
  apples = abs(rnorm(15, 5, 2)),
  pears = abs(rnorm(15, 4, 1)),
  bananas = abs(rnorm(15, 6, 2))
) %>%
  pivot_longer(
    cols = c(apples, bananas, pears),
    names_to = "variable",
    values_to = "value"
  ) %>%
  mutate(
    country = fct_relevel(country, c("DNK", "FIN", "AUS")),
    cyear = paste0(country, year)
  )

t %>%
  ggplot(aes(fill = variable, y = value, x = year)) + # change to year rather than cyear
  scale_fill_brewer(name = "Fruits") +
  geom_bar(position = "fill", stat = "identity") +
  labs(x = "Year", y = "Variable", title = "Title") + # change x-axis label
  theme_bw() +
  facet_grid(~country) # choose country variable to facet by
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2021-04-30 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v1.0.0)</sup>

This also eliminates the need to rotate the years on the x-axis.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. I had also considered `facet_grid()`. Unfortunately this doesn't work since I have too many `country` entries and the 'year' entries are irregular (making the labels overlap and overcrowd the shared x-axis when using `facet_wrap()`).

Comment: Thanks for the info - I've added another possible solution @Ivo

Comment: I've also followed up on the `facet_wrap()` solution, and `ggforce::facet_wrap_paginate()` allows splitting this over multiple pages.